# Is this a WPF Datagrid bug?

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid

I have the following proof of concept:

XAML window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=Enabled}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Data> Items { get; private set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<Data>();
        this.DataContext = this;
        for (int index = 0; index < 30; index++)
        {
            this.Items.Add(new Data() {Enabled = true });   
        }
    }
}

public class Data
{
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
}
}
```

Execute the app, uncheck some boxes at the top, scroll down, change some boxes again and scroll up. Voilá, the checkboxes are checked again!

Am I missing something or should I fill a bug to Microsoft?

**EDIT**: Thanks for your responses but it's not related with the INotify or the Checkbox, with a TextBox and the INotify the same happens. You don't event need to click the checkboxes after scrolling, just uncheck some, scroll down, scroll up and voila, they are checked again.  Check this code:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=Enabled}" />
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
</Window>
```

And the code behind:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Data> Items { get; private set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<Data>();
        this.DataContext = this;
        for (int index = 0; index < 30; index++)
        {
            this.Items.Add(new Data() { Enabled = true, Text = index.ToString() });
        }
    }
}

public class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _enabled;
    public bool Enabled
    {
        get { return _enabled; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _enabled)
            {
                _enabled = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Enabled");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _text)
            {
                _text = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Text");
            }
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
}
```

Comment: Does your result change if you make `Data` inherit from `INotifyPropertyChanged` and use property change notifications?

Comment: Try turning recycling off.  Does the set get called?  If not UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged".  And INotify like Rachel said.

Comment: I would try what Rachel suggested.

Comment: I would do what Rachel suggested, and try EnableRowVirtualization="false".

Comment: @Rachel no, the result does not change :(

Comment: @Blam what means "turning recycling off"?

Comment: @Negative it does not make any difference :(

Comment: @Xcalibur37 that's it! With EnableRowVirtualization set to false the grid works as expected! Is this a bug of the virtualization feature???

Comment: Search msnd on virtualization recycling  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizationmode.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've entered a defect at Microsoft because this is not the expected way of working wherever or not VirtualRows are used.

Bug report [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/754753/wrong-data-in-wpf-datagrid-when-using-enablerowvirtualization-and-datagridtemplatecolumns)

Answer (score 6):

This problem isn't related to recycling. In fact, disabling recycling hides the real problem: your `Data` object properties are never updated. Try to set a breakpoint in the `Enabled` or `Text` setter and you'll see that nothing will happen when you change the text or check/unchecked the box. When you scroll away and back, the property is reread from the object, and since it hasn't changed, the checkbox is correctly updated to match the `Enabled` property.

A `DataGrid` is meant to have all rows in display mode by default, with the user switching to editing mode on the currently selected row when he needs to. The values aren't committed until the user validates the whole row.

Behind the scenes, an implicit [`BindingGroup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindinggroup.aspx) is created for the whole row, effectively setting all the bindings to [`UpdateSourceTrigger.Explicit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger.aspx). This binding group is committed when the user is done editing the row. In your case, since there is no `BeginEdit`, there won't be any `CommitEdit` and the values won't ever be updated.

You have several solutions here:

- Use another control that doesn't have this "switch to edit mode" behavior, such as a `ListView`.
- Force the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged` or `LostFocus` on every binding.
- Change how the user uses the grid to comply with the `DataGrid` behavior.